# What to respond to AJAX request in a django application's python code?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have AJAX script running on my Django application, but at the moment the script does not change the content of my page. I'm trying to get content from a sub-url, but only my HTTP-side of things works as it should, whereas AJAX does nothing (although the AJAX-code will be ran).

I'm wondering what I need to respond to the AJAX request with in order to give it the directions it needs to replicate the behaviour of what my HTTPResponse does, but with AJAX principles (not changing the actual page)

My views.py has the lines

```
if not request.is_ajax():
    return render(request, "selectui/index.html", context)
return render(request, "selectui/countrytable.html", context)
```

This "works", but my current problem is that the response to an ajax call now contains html, which it should not. What should I pass instead to avoid passing html, but still pass the correct URL to the script?

Script:

```
$(function() {
    "use strict";

    $("#continentMenu a").on("click", function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr("href");

        $("#continentName").text($(this).text());

        $("#tableContainer").load(url);
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, your Ajax response is specifically set to be empty. If you want to load data, you need to send some.

Comment: I had been passing the wrong URL in my code in my tries, so when I added the URL below that one in hierarchy, it works the way I wanted to, thanks.

Comment: Actually another question would be how I can do it without passing html in the response? 

I'll edit the code of the question accordingly

Comment: But I'm not sure why you think the Ajax response "shouldn't" contain HTML. Why not? It's a perfectly valid thing to do.

Comment: The automatic tester I'm using (and have to use for this) contains the line `self.assertNotContains(response, "<html>")` where `response` is `response = self.client.get(url, HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')`. As for the reasoning, I don't know.

Comment: Well, that part I probably agree with; you need to respond with a template fragment, not a full HTML page. You should ensure that countrytable.html doesn't extend a base template that includes the full HTML boilerplate, just the div or whatever that you want.

Comment: I had `{% extends "base.html" %}` in the HTML it was loading, and removing it fixed the problem. What exactly happens when that is in the HTML, then? But thanks anyway, that fixed the problem. If you want, you can make it an answer I can accept (removal of `{% extends "base.html" %}` in the HTML the url links to)